# Why ImageView taking from different size for iphone 6 and 6 plus?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

I made an xib in XCode 6 and put a imageView on it in ANY | ANY of frame say : (0,0,20,20)

Then, I resized the same frame in Compact | Regular (For all iphones in portrait) : say (0,0,30,30)

[image]

Once I am checking same in debugger for iPhone 6 and 6 plus, it is taking image of frame (0,0,30,30).
But it is working fine for iPhone 5 and 5S

What is the reason for this ?

Comment: so what is the issue? you set frame (0,0,30,30) for compact regular and you are getting same frame.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 6 and 6 plus resolution is different than 5s. So it will increase image views frame. If you want to set image with fixed height and width, you need to set constraints as per requirement. Happy coding..! :)